# for every value in array B, want to find the consecutive values in A

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I'm trying to write a small JS program. For every value in array B, I want to find the consecutive values in A that sum to that value of B.

I'm trying to print the element in the array A such that it matches the consecutive sum in array B.

I wrote the code on [this JSFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/3pc69ywh/1/) but I'm not sure if B contains N elements...

Could you tell me how to write it in jQuery? Output it should element in myArray such that it matches the consecutive sum in myOtherArray
myArray[0] + myArray1 will not work if it contains N elements.

```
var myArray = [ 2, 3, 4 ];

var myOtherArray = [ 5, 6, 7 ];

for ( var i = 0; i < myOtherArray.length; i++ ) {


    for ( var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++ ) {


          if ( myOtherArray[i] == myArray[0] +myArray[1] ) {
             console.log (myArray[ i ]);
          }

          else if(myOtherArray[i] == myArray[1] +myArray[2]) {
              console.log (myArray[ i ]);
          }

        else{
            console.log ("no matching");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Will there always be a match? Are all numbers different?

Comment: Need to define criteria in more concise terms. As it stands right now it is not very clear what objective is ... for  example what is `consecutive sum`? SHow expected results

Comment: Be aware, this has nothing to do with jQuery. If you want to tag spam, use tag: 'heal the world'

Comment: consecutive sum means 2+3 of array is equal to 5 of array 2

Comment: @juvian yeah nos are different...certain scenario there might be match

Comment: @A.Wolff can u tell me how to do in js

Comment: @mapuut I'm afraid, i'm not sure to understand the question. You should provide concrete example of what you are looking for in question

Comment: myArray[1] and myArray[2] will always execute as 2+3, regardless of the loop. You need to use your indexes. like myArray[i] + myArray[i+1]. But even then, you'd most likely run into out of array index exceptions. This also looks like a homework problem as well.

Comment: @sksallaj not a homework byt trying to improve my js skills...can u update in my fiddle

Comment: @all: is this correct http://jsfiddle.net/3pc69ywh/2/

Comment: Is a consecutive sum always exactly two values that are added, not more or less?

Comment: Guys, he wanted to see if the sum of two consecutive values, iterated along the array will sum up to any values found in the second array. My solution clears up the confusion in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a gamble by answering this.. but I'm assuming that you want to keep on adding two indexes within your array that are next to each other, to see if they'd equal any value in your second array?

Also, I have no idea why you're using a nested loop. You only need to traverse one array, not two.

```
var myArray = [ 2, 3, 4 ];
var myOtherArray = [ 5, 6, 7 ];
var sum = 0;

for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.length-1; i++ ) {
    sum = myArray[i] +myArray[i+1];
    if (myOtherArray.indexOf[sum] != -1 ) {
        console.log ("matching");
    }
    else {
         console.log ("no matching");
    }
}
```

the result should spit out "matching" twice.

Because 2+3 = 5, which exists in the second array. And 3+4 = 7, which also exists in the second array.

Comment: @sksallai can you tell me why you are checking with condition -1  if (myOtherArray.indexOf[sum] != -1 )

Comment: myOtherArray.indexOf[sum] return -1 if there is no result found in the array. Also in the second for loop, I made it so that j < myArray.length-1, because you don't need to loop to the last index, the logic takes care of that for you.

Comment: if i want to print the matching some then i should change console,log like this right http://jsfiddle.net/qm3a1dw4/

Comment: yes, but look at my newest edit, you need one loop, not two. I tried to change your code with minimal changes to the logic as possible. But if I'm on the same page as you, then the second loop isn't really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the criteria is not well defined I believe this might be similar to what you are looking for

```
var sum = 0;

for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
    sum += myArray[j];
    var isMatch = myOtherArray.indexOf(sum) > -1,
        matchText = isMatch ? ' true' : ' false';
    $('body').append('Match for ' + sum + ' is' + matchText + '<br>')
}
```

It sums all elements within the array up to the current index and checks if that value exists in other array

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/va1e64s3/)**</kbd>

Comment: I don't know. You have not defined the criteria very well or provided expected results

Comment: @charlieftl can you tell me why you are checking with condition -1  if (myOtherArray.indexOf[sum] != -1 )

Comment: because that's how `indexOf()` works. Will return `-1` for no match

Answer (score 0):

Answer to how i understood the question: http://jsfiddle.net/qqqs8aLc/1/

```
var A = [ 5, 6, 7 ];
var B = [ 2, 3, 4 ];

var Alen = A.length;
var Blen = B.length;

for(var i=0; i < Alen; i++){

     for(var j=0; j < Blen; j++){

        if(A[i] == (B[j] + B[j+1])){
            console.log("%d = (%d, %d)",A[i], B[j], B[j+1]);
        }
    }
}
```